# Waiting textbox showing

Tags: vb.net, string, if-statement, textbox

So I'm kind of new to VB.NET on Visual Studio 2010 and I'm trying to do like a simple "cripter" I think. So basically what I'm doing is every time someone puts a letter or number, on the textbox it gives a random string.  So the user puts on the textbox the letter A and gives the string 1123k.
Is there anyway that I can do so that the after message where shows 1123k only show when button1 is clicked?  Because if the user puts abc it will show 3 times the same string.  Heres little bit of the code.

```
If (TextBox1.Text = ("b")) Then
    MessageBox.Show("ak281a")
End If
```

Comment: Do not use the TextChanged event then

Comment: You're writing VB.NET code, not C#.  There is a distinct difference.  Also, post more of your code - the little snippet you posted does not give nearly enough context.

Comment: Also: there's no such thing as "virtual basic 2010". It's Visual Basic.Net and Visual Studio 2010.

Comment: @Isaac 1. Generate random string - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1122483/random-string-generator-returning-same-string 2. Associate chars with string - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10250232/what-is-the-easiest-way-to-handle-associative-array-in-c

Answer (score 0):

Try to use a switch case for any case you have

```
string text = TextBox1.ToString();
Switch (text)
      case A:
            break;
        ...
      case Z:
            break;
```